# ArcPy equivalent for Data -> Export Data

Tags: arcpy, arcmap

[image: Export Raster Data]

I'm trying to figure out what Python command can be called to replicate the Data -> Extract data 'Export Raster Data' dialog box.  I'm running ArcMap 10.3 . I would like to automate this using ArcPy but I am unable to figure out what to call.

Comment: [Copy Raster](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.4/tools/data-management-toolbox/copy-raster.htm)

Comment: Or raster to other format, more flexible

Answer (score 1):

You can probably use the Copy Raster tool to achieve this task. The following link has python code: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/2.8/tool-reference/data-management/copy-raster.htm.

Comment: @user2856
Neither of these suggestions has work.  I am only able to get out another single band floating point tif image.  I am trying to get out an RBG image that can be viewed in a standard viewing program.  I have tried colormap to rgb option of Copy Raster tool, but despite having a color ramp applied, this fails.  I guess there is a difference between a color map and a color ramp as the properties of my raster data set show no color map exist though I do have a color ramp applied in symbology.

Please help. This is the last piece of the puzzle for me.  Thnx